# Angular Stormpath Injection Unknown Providor

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, browserify, commonjs, stormpath

I'm trying to use the angular ui router with storm path for angular, but I keep getting an unknown provider error. My code is as follows,

```
var angular = require("angular");

// app.js
var app = angular.module('app', [require('angular-ui-router'), require("stormpath-sdk-angularjs")]);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'partials/home.html'
    })
    .state('about', {
        url: '/about',
        templateUrl: 'partials/about.html'
    });
})
.run(function($stormpath){
  $stormpath.uiRouter({
    loginState: 'login',
    defaultPostLoginState: 'home'
  });
});
```

And here is the error page,[Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=$stormpathProvider%20%3C-%20$stormpath)

Comment: I'd say the problem is here ~ https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-angularjs/blob/master/dist/stormpath-sdk-angularjs.js#L12. They've used the wrong name in their `module.exports`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stormpath are using the wrong module name in their `module.exports` (I've raised a bug here ~ https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-angularjs/issues/80).

For now, you can do this

```
var angular = require("angular");
require('stormpath-sdk-angularjs');

// app.js
var app = angular.module('app', [
    require('angular-ui-router'), // this one is fine
    'stormpath',
    'stormpath.templates'
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for reporting this bug - it has been fixed in the latest version: https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-angularjs/pull/81

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug `stormpath-sdk-angularjs` and has been fixed in version `0.8.2`.

To get it to work with browserify, please add these lines to your `package.json`:

```js
"browser": {
  "stormpath": "./node_modules/stormpath-sdk-angularjs/dist/stormpath-sdk-angularjs.js",
  "stormpath.templates": "./node_modules/stormpath-sdk-angularjs/dist/stormpath-sdk-angularjs.tpls.js"
}
```

And then require it like:

```js
var angular = require("angular");

var app = angular.module('app', [
  require('angular-ui-router'),
  require('stormpath'),
  require('stormpath.templates')
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you do not use the require() in the angular dependency list in this way. Rather you need:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui-router','stormpath']);
```

Make sure that both libraries are properly included.

Comment: I'm using browserify, which worked for just the ui-router so I assume it is valid. Also I looked at the stormpath package at it contained an index.js file, which makes me assume it can be included. I assume there is some issue with my arguments structure for the run function.

Comment: I see that. Try just not using require for stormpath then and just put `'stormpath'` as the module dependency and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is likely part of the solution.  Perhaps you are using a tool to compile your application such as WebPack?  That information would be useful.  Please note that the Stormpath Angular SDK provides two modules in the Angular namespace, `stormpath` and `stormpath.templates`.  If using browserify, you may need to use  `require('dist/stormpath-sdk-angularjs.js')`

P.S. I work at [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com), please feel free to reach us via support@stormpath.com if you would like to privately share your code with us.  Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have `module.exports = 'ui.router'` in [`dist/stormpath-sdk-angularjs.js`](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-angularjs/blob/master/dist/stormpath-sdk-angularjs.js#L12)?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out the stormpath sdk injects itself into angular. The solution is to load the library after angular.

```
var angular = require("angular");
var stormpath = require("stormpath-sdk-angularjs");

var app = angular.module('app', [require('angular-ui-router'), "stormpath", "stormpath.templates"]);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
    //States Here
})
.run(function($stormpath){
    $stormpath.uiRouter({
        loginState: 'login',
        defaultPostLoginState: 'home'
    });
});
```